# TokenService Error: ChainId 0x539 is not supported in privately deployed blockchain

Tags: blockchain, solidity, metamask

when trying to import a custom ERC20 token deployed in that network, MM acts weirdly:

after entering the custom token’s address - MM shows a Symbol and Decimals according to the contract.
after pressing the “Add custom token” button - it correctly indicates the current balance in the next window.
then after pressing the “Import tokens” button window closes and just nothing happens…

The error appears only in the browser dev console

> Error: TokenService Error: ChainId 0x539 is not supported

I am trying to add tokens to mywallet but not able to do it